# Ручная реализация выпадающего списка ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, combobox

Написал Listbox, выглядит так:

[image: custom Listbox]

Теперь нужно сделать **Combobox**, но не могу понять одного нюанса. Если все предыдущие контролы имели конкретный указанный размер (Checkbox, Label, Textbox, Button) то при раскрытии Combobox визуально его размер увеличивается до определённого максимума, указанного в свойствах.

Каким образом сделать "выпадающее меню" (по сути комбобокс это стилизованная кнопка + выпадающий поверх всего и за границы окна листбокс)? 
Может нужно делать дочернюю форму, и отлавливать потерю фокуса или выбор элемента?

Ввод текста не предполагается. Только выбор одного из представленных элементов. Так-же вариант с Dialog формой не нравится в связи с потерей фокуса формы родителя.

Comment: "по сути комбобокс это стилизованная кнопка ..." - нет, это специальный объект Windows.

Comment: я имел ввиду в плане реализации. элемент по типу кнопки с текстом. есть идеи как сделать такой контрол наследуясь от UserControl ?

Comment: Не надо этого делать. You will be fighting Windows every step of the way.

Comment: За что пытаетесь закрыть? о_О

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос с использованием отдельной формы.
Для автоматического скрытия формы при потере "фокуса" используется такой  переопределенный метод :

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        const UInt32 WM_NCACTIVATE = 0x0086;

        bool handled = false;
        if (m.Msg == WM_NCACTIVATE && m.WParam.ToInt32() == 0)
        {
            handled = true;
            Close();
        }

        if (!handled)
            base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Выползающий список — это полноценное окно верхнего уровня. Это окно не дочернее, и размеры оригинального контрола не меняются.

Чтобы решить проблему потери фокуса, воспользуйтесь `Form.ShowWithoutActivation`:

```
protected override bool ShowWithoutActivation
{
    get { return true; }
}
```

P. S. Вы идёте неэффективным путём. Если вам нужна сложная стилизация контролов и при этом не убитые в ноль usability и accessibility (логики в стандартных контролах больше, чем вы думаете), то посмотрите в сторону WPF. Там это стилизация поддерживается из коробки и не требует велосипедного переписывания всех контролов с нуля.

Comment: Проект Winforms, контролы нужно делать исключительно под него. Максимально приближенной логики к стандартным контролам не нужно, т.к. взаимодействие с ними будет ограниченно коротким списком хоткеев либо с использованием тачскрина для примитивных операций.

Comment: @Newbie127 Можно переходить на WPF постепенно, контролы WinForms и WPF прекрасно уживаются в одном диалоге.

Comment: Мы переходим с WPF обратно на winforms. Не спрашивайте почему. Не хочется вспоминать притчу о ответах на наших и зарубежных сайтах. Есть ответ, совет, напутствие конкретно по моему вопросу - пожалуйста. Но давайте без холиваров!

Comment: @Newbie127 Производительность что ли?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, нужен комбобокс, при раскрытии становящийся похожим на показанный в вопросе листбокс, то есть без поля ввода.

Попробуйте использовать стандартный ComboBox, определив два обработчика событий:

```
comboBox.DropDown += (o, e) =>
{
    comboBox.Top -= comboBox.Height;
    comboBox.Hide();
};

comboBox.DropDownClosed += (o, e) =>
{
    comboBox.Top += comboBox.Height;
    comboBox.Show();
};
```

Подберите подходящее значение свойства `DropDownHeight`.

Для дальнейшей кастомизации следует установить свойство

```
comboBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
```

и определить обработчик события `DrawItem`.

При этом можно использовать все имеющиеся возможности комбобокса, будь то привязка данных, AutoComplete и прочие.